# What are good permissions for a USB disk when security does not matter?

Tags: linux, permissions, external-hard-drive, ext

I have an ext4 formatted usb hard disk, I want to use to move between different computers with different users. How should I set its directories' permissions it, so that every user can r/w? What should file permissions look like (its mainly movies and mp3s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't care who writes what where, and assuming the disk is mounted at `/mnt/media-disk`, then the best way to set full permissions for everyone would be to run these two commands:

```
find /mnt/media-disk/ -type f -exec chmod 666 {} \;
find /mnt/media-disk/ -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
```

The first command will set read and write permissions for everyone, on every file on the disk; the second will set read, write, and execute permissions, on every directory. (On directories, execute permission enables traversal, i.e., descent past that directory into others contained within it.)

For more details, try `man find` and `man chmod` at any shell prompt.

Comment: Isn't 777 execute, too?

Comment: Whoops, so it is -- probably wouldn't matter, but I'll edit the question all the same.

Comment: Glad to be of help!